# ExtJS 3 - File Upload

Tags: extjs, file-upload, extjs3

How can I upload a file using ExtJS 3?

I watched this exmpale:

[Upload File Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/file-upload.html)

But it seems like an Ext 4 example.

Anyone knows?

Comment: Got this example on extJS 3.3.1 [link](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/form/file-upload.html), but it uses xtype:'fileuploadfield' that is not recongnized according to the API of ExtJS 3.3.1 that is shown here [link](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.x/docs/)

Comment: according to [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.BasicForm-cfg-fileUpload).  There is an attribute `fileUpload` on `BasicForm` that may accomplish?

Comment: found it. it can be use also within FormPanel. all you need is to set some item of the FormPanel to the xtype:'textField' and configure it's  inputType:'file'. That does the work.  Thanks for the answer though.    But the weird part is that this thing only work with xtype:'textField' and not with other xtypes such as 'button', 'textarea' etc.   Do you know the reason perhaps?

Comment: I'm not positive why it would only be implemented on the textfield, that's a good question tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no file upload component in ExtJS 3, but you can create one using this example :
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/form/file-upload.html

This example use a custom component for the file upload field (see http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/form/file-upload.js). 
Also don't forget to set `fileUpload` to `true` on your form.

*Edit 4 years later :* it seems that Sencha has removed the examples page for ExtJS 3, but you can still access a copy here : http://svn.geoext.org/ext/3.4.0/examples/form/file-upload.html

Comment: Thanks. Already solved it by this same example. Gonna accept your answer because of your good intention :)